# XSLT: how to sort date

Tags: xml, sorting, xslt

I have a question about sort date time.

I found a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15362667/sorting-xslt-by-date-and-time) but this solution is not work for me.

suppose I have a xml. The date order is month, day and year.

```
<persons>
  <person>
     <name>1</name>
     <birthday>021514</birthday>
  </person>
  <person>
     <name>2</name>
     <birthday>051513</birthday>
  </person>
</persons>
```

I have a xsl

```
        <xsl:for-each select="//person">
            <!-- day -->
            <xsl:sort select="substring(birthday, 3, 2)" order="descending" data-type="number"/>
            <!-- month -->
            <xsl:sort select="substring(birthday, 1, 2)" order="descending" data-type="number"/>
            <!-- year -->
            <xsl:sort select="substring(birthday, 5, 2)" order="descending" data-type="number"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="birthday"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
```

I want the date sort in decreasing order.

I get result

```
051513
021514
```

but the actual result I want is

```
021514
051513
```

Only the first sort is working. The rest of sorts are not working.
What's wrong with this code? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are all the people you are dealing with younger than 14?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change order of sorting conditions.
You should start by Year, Month and Day.

```
<xsl:for-each select="//person">
  <!-- year -->
  <xsl:sort select="substring(birthday, 5, 2)" order="descending" data-type="number"/>
  <!-- month -->
  <xsl:sort select="substring(birthday, 1, 2)" order="descending" data-type="number"/>
  <!-- day -->
  <xsl:sort select="substring(birthday, 3, 2)" order="descending" data-type="number"/>
  <xsl:value-of select="birthday"/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have XML using MMDDYY as the date format then it is badly designed XML, and the best thing to do with badly designed XML is to clean it up in a preprocessing phase before you do anything else. Write a stylesheet whose only purpose is to clean the XML up into something better, and then think about the transformation tasks as a separate processing phase.

In this case you want to create dates in the ISO form YYYY-MM-DD. I'm not sure what your rule is for inferring the century, but I would write something like the following (needs XSLT 2.0):

```
<xsl:template match="birthday">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:variable name="year" select="substring(., 5, 2)"/>
    <xsl:variable name="month" select="substring(., 1, 2)"/>
    <xsl:variable name="day" select="substring(., 3, 2)"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="if (number($year) gt 20 then '19' else '20'"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="$year, $month, $day" separator="-"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```